# Enumerate within group by n rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in which I have to enumerate rows in group by n elements

For example, if n=3, I would like to get the following result:

```
 initial table    result table      
 | ID | DATA |    | ID | DATA |
 |----|------|    |----|------|
 | 1  | a    |    | 1  | 1 a  |
 | 2  | b    |    | 2  | 2 b  |
 | 3  | c    |    | 3  | 3 c  |
 | 4  | d    |    | 4  | 1 d  |
 | 5  | e    |    | 5  | 2 e  |
 | 6  | f    |    | 6  | 3 f  |
 | 7  | g    |    | 7  | 1 g  |`
```

I already did what I need with the following code:

```
UPDATE test 
    SET data = i.num +''+ data
     FROM (
      Select id, cast(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [num] ORDER BY [num])as char) as num 
      from (select id, (row_number() over (order by id)+2 )/3  as num from test) j) i
    WHERE 
        i.id = test.id
```

However, I think there is a better way. I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

Your method is fine.  I would use an updatable CTE with the modulo operator:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             cast( 1 + (row_number() over (order by id) - 1) % 3 as varchar(255)) as num3
      from test t
     ) 
update toupdate 
    set data = num3 + ' ' + data;
```